# Trying to Insert an input function using Python in OpenAI

Tags: python, openai-api

```
import os
import openai
openai.api_key = 'API_Key'
Question = "\\n\\nQ: input("Enter Question")?\\nA:",
response = openai.Completion.create(
model="text-davinci-003",
prompt= Question,
temperature=0,
max_tokens=100,
top_p=1,
frequency_penalty=0.0,
presence_penalty=0.0,
stop=\["\\n"\]
)
print( str(response\['choices'\]\[0\]\['text'\]))`
```

```
ERROR
File "C:\\Users\\yus\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\TEST.py", line 6
Question = "\\n\\nQ: "Input_Question"  \\nA:"
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Expecting an input function to ask to enter a question and then print the answer using OpenAI.

Comment: Line 6 should be something like ```Question = input("Enter Question: ")```

Comment: Enter Question: what is water

{
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "stop",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "text": ""
    }
  ],
  "created": 1672826805,
  "id": "cmpl-6UuxRq4iFEkLN9TXB0UnuXCjOBN0e",
  "model": "text-davinci-003",
  "object": "text_completion",
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 3,
    "total_tokens": 3
  }
}

Process finished with exit code 0

did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how is done

```
 def main():
      form = cgi.FieldStorage()
      IN = form.getvalue("query")
      QT = f"Q: {IN}  ? A:"
      response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=QT,
        temperature=0,
        max_tokens=64,
        top_p=1,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0,
        stop=["\n\n"]
      )
      print(str(response['choices'][0]['text']))
   
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).